# Django и gettext, как правильно разделить текст и код?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-3.5, gettext

Как можно решить задачу по разделению выводимого текста и кода, а в коде писать только ключ?

Задача: Необходимо вынести весь текст из кода и из шаблона допустим в json файл.

На данный момент есть вот такой вариант решения:

```
{
    'sc.site_name' : 'Site name',
    'sc.phone_number' : 'Phone number',
    'sc.email' : 'E-mail',
    'sc.skype' : 'Skype',
}
```

И пример в модели:

```
class SiteConfiguration(SingletonModel):
    site_name = models.CharField(verbose_name = json_local['sc.site_name'])
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(verbose_name = json_local['sc.phone_number'])
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name = json_local['sc.email'])
    skype = models.CharField(verbose_name = json_local['sc.skype'])
```

---

#### Дополнил вопрос:

Возможно подобный подход использовать в связки с gettext?
Я возможно не понимаю зачем нужен gettext, но на сколько эффективно в плане производительности и удобства хранить текст в *.po файлах и использовать  в msgid ключи?

Пример структуры в JSON (для наглядного примера):

```
{
   'sc.site_name': {
       'ru': 'Имя сайта',
       'us': 'Site name',
       ...
   }
   ...
}
```

И в фале *.po:

```
# ru.po
msgid "sc.site_name"
msgstr "Название сайта"

# us.po
msgid "sc.site_name"
msgstr "Site name"
```

Comment: В джанге же есть все встроенные инструменты по интернационализации с gettext, в подробностях описываемые в официальном учебнике, почему бы не использовать их? Только вместо английских фраз использовать эти самые ключи

Comment: @andreymal меня как раз это и интересует, на сколько правильно использовать место фразы ключ

Comment: Вообще это вроде как неправильно неправильно независимо от конкретной реализации (ибо если немного поменяется формулировка, но не поменяется ключ, то очень легко забыть поправить формулировку во всех языках, в то время как при использовании английской фразы в качестве ключа изменится она сама и все утилиты для перевода заявят о неполном переводе, забыть становится трудно), но многие так делают и им норм, а использовать ключ с gettext или без gettext вроде принципиальной разницы нет, но если он идёт с django из коробки, то почему бы и нет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение с использованием gettext, в коде использую ключи:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

text = _("sc.site_name")
```

И присваиваю ключу строчку в файлах *.po:

```
# ru.po
msgid "sc.site_name"
msgstr "Название сайта"

# us.po
msgid "sc.site_name"
msgstr "Site name"
```

Answer (score 2):

Для этой задачи также можно использовать метод [get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=get%20method#dict.get), он отличается тем, что вы не получите `KeyError`, в случае, если забудете указать какое-либо значение. Результатом будет `None` или то, что вы указали вторым аргументом.

```
json_local.get('sc.site_name', 'default_field_name')
```

Также можно хранить строки в отдельном модуле в виде переменных и импортировать этот модуль там, где это необходимо.